# How to detect if a hyperlink has been clicked in a WebView in Metro?

Tags: microsoft-metro

Is there anyway i can get the hyperlink click in webview to my c# with Hyperlink value in Metro?. I am using WebView..NavigateToString() to generate the content?.

Answer (score 5):

You can call `InvokeScript` with some of your own Javascript to set up a listener for when the user navigates away from your page. This would look something like the following in C#:

```
var navigationListenerString = @"
(function() {
  function leavingPage() {
    window.external.notify("LEAVING PAGE");
  }
  window.onbeforeunload = leavingPage;
})()";

webView.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { navigationListenerString });
```

Then you can use `ScriptNotify` to listen for your particular message to determine that the page is unloading and the user is leaving. Unfortunately you cannot detect where a user is going. Also, if the hyperlink opens in a new window and the webview does not unload, you cannot detect that either.

Answer (score 1):

Since WebView in windows 8 doesn't support Navigating() events like the Silverlight WebBrowser control, thus it is not possible to get hyperlink or cancel navigation.

But since you're using NavigateToString() method, you can write some manual javascript code and achieve same with the help of WebView.ScriptNotify() event.